# jquery mobile listview - touchstart event to fire on <li> element

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile

When I try and fire an event on a listview `<li>` item it seems that the whole element is not considered, but only the elements inside it:

```
<ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-filter-placeholder='Search Your Trucks..' data-inset='true' data-mini='true'>
    <li id=tg_1><a id=tg_2 href=#divdet>ONE</a> TEST </li>
    <li id=tg_2><a id=tg_2 href=#divdet>TWO</a> FOO </li>
</ul>
```

The function handling touchstart (which handles touchstart of multiple elements):

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    switch(e.target.id) {
        case ...
            ..other elements...
            break;
        default:
            if(e.target.id.substr(0,3) == "tg_")
                $.ajax({
                     ... do request ....
                })
               $("#divdet").html(from_ajax_data);
            }
    }
}
```

The issue is that it is working, but only when clicking on specific parts of the `<li>` element. I'd like it to work every time a `<li>` is clicked.

The concept is that with the href i can move to the next page of the app using effect such as slide, whilst with the touch event I load data into the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move to the next page with transition using script as well:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change

```
<ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-filter-placeholder='Search Your Trucks..' data-inset='true' data-mini='true'>
    <li id="tg_1"><a id="tg_1a" href="#">ONE</a> TEST </li>
    <li id="tg_2"><a id="tg_2a" href="#">TWO</a> FOO </li>
</ul>

$(document).on("click", "li", function(e){        
    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    if(id && id.substr(0,3) == "tg_") {
        var from_ajax_data = "from ajax html"; //ajax call here
        $("#divdet").html(from_ajax_data);
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#divdet", { transition: "slide" } );
     }    
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/thqw05nn/)**